# Error parsing XML: not well formed(invalid token)- can't spot error

Tags: android

Can someone spot the error in my AndroidManifest.xml? To me I have all the tags correct.
I have checked the other questions but have not spotted anything. The X in eclipse is on the application start tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="***"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="18"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

 <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
   <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.msc.mymedisense.Welcome"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.msc.mymedisense.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:parentActivityName="com.msc.mymedisense.Welcome" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.msc.mymedisense.Welcome" />
        </activity>
        <activity
              android:name=".AppSettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_AppSettings">
         </activity>
         <activity
              android:name=".NotificationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_notification">
         </activity>
           <receiver android:name=".TimeAlarm" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>  
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: "Not well-formed" sounds weird to me, as there are no syntax errors as checked by http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: I'd just add a space before /> in uses-permission. Other than this, it seems perfect, to me.

Comment: Tip: Select all the text and do CTRL-i for consistent code formatting (Eclipse). Otherwise I see no problem with a quick glance.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Are there any suggestions on hpw to get rid of that Error

Comment: Thank you so much Ernir Erlingsson....the CTRL i did the trick

Comment: For curiosity: did it add the space at the end of uses-permission?